# How can i get the json body of this GET request?

Tags: java, get, unirest

I am using the Dank Memer imgen api to manipulate images.
To perform the GET request, i used the Unirest-Java. (https://kong.github.io/unirest-java/)

The code looks like this:

```
HttpResponse<JsonNode> response = Unirest.get("https://dankmemer.services/api/changemymind")
                  .header("Authorization", "tokenhere")
                  .queryString("text", "I am a human")
                  .asJson();
```

If i request the Headers with `response.getHeaders()` it returns this:

```
Date: Mon, 02 Dec 2019 17:07:08 GMT
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Set-Cookie: __cfduid=dd737927432f802b76c89b2fa8ee72e171575306428; expires=Wed, 01-Jan-20 17:07:08 GMT; path=/; domain=.dankmemer.services; HttpOnly; Secure
Cache-Control: public, max-age=43200
Expires: Tue, 03 Dec 2019 05:07:08 GMT
X-RateLimit-Limit: 5
X-RateLimit-Remaining: 4
X-RateLimit-Reset: 1575306429645
X-Global-RateLimit-Limit: 300
X-Global-RateLimit-Remaining: 299
X-Global-RateLimit-Reset: 1575306488643
CF-Cache-Status: DYNAMIC
Expect-CT: max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"
Server: cloudflare
CF-RAY: 53eee53a48a5d709-FRA
```

However i need to get the response body which returns null when i request it.

```
response.getBody();

// returns null.
// Also returns null when i put:  response.getBody.toString();
```

How do i display the body?

Comment: I don't know anything about this Unirest API, but calling `asJson()` and expecting an HttpResponse<JsonNode> looks wrong, since the response body is a JPEG image, and not a JSON document.

Comment: You should check the API docs of the server. Maybe you're getting an image url? An image in base64 format? Maybe the response is not JSON. What is the response code you're getting? Maybe even though the response content type is set to image, you're having an issue. Check how you should expect the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried getting the response as a file and store it.
This worked perfectly.

```
HttpResponse<File> response = Unirest.get("https://dankmemer.services/api/changemymind")
                  .header("Authorization", "tokenhere")
                  .queryString("text", "i am a human" )
                  .asFile("C:\\Users\\PC\\Some Folder\\changemymind.jpg");
```